# Package formular doesn't respect line spacing

Tags: xetex, line-spacing

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, table]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{formular}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\linespread{1.3}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmathfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}

\setFRMfontencoding{\encodingdefault}
\setFRMdfontencoding{\encodingdefault}
\setFRMfontfamily{\sfdefault}
\setFRMdfontfamily{\sfdefault}
\setFRMinlinestyle\setFRMfontsize{14pt}\newFRMenvironment{specialFRM}{This stuff breaks }{2}

\begin{document}
\begin{specialFRM}First Line \\Second Line \end{specialFRM}
\end{document}
```

I have tried looking into CTAN package manual, but English isn't my first language, so I don't understand what I need to do to make this package respect line spacing: https://ctan.org/pkg/formular. Compiler is xetex.

[image]

Comment: the package uses its own baseline setting, you have increased the document baseline by 1.3 but you have decreased the packge baseline from its default 18pt to 14pt, perhaps you want  something bigger like `\setFRMbaselineskip{24pt}` instead?

Comment: Yes, I removed \setFRMbaselineskip{14pt} from the MWE, it still breaks. I actually tried to fix it with \setFRMbaselineskip{24pt} but it didn't work - it moves the line further down with the text.

Comment: oh I see what you mean, the coding in the package is a little strange:-)

Comment: What I want is to get a second line that doesn't get crossed in the picture, my goal is quite simple. But for whatever reason `formular` just doesn't want to respect line spacing and thinks it works in a one-space environment. So "Second line" that is controlled by \\ gets shifted down further than formular expects, and gets crossed by formulars line. Unfortunately, \setFRMbaselineskip{24pt} just shifts both the line and the "Second line" further down.

Answer (score 1):

The package doesn't cope with `\linespread` that is probably fixable but would take multiple changes all over, simpler is to locally set it back to 1 then use the packages own command to set the font size and baselineskip_

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, table]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{formular}
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\linespread{1.3}


\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmathfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}

\setFRMfontencoding{\encodingdefault}
\setFRMdfontencoding{\encodingdefault}



\setFRMfontfamily{\sfdefault}
\setFRMdfontfamily{\sfdefault}
\setFRMinlinestyle
\setFRMfontsize{14pt}
\setFRMbaselineskip{34pt}
\newFRMenvironment{specialFRM}{This stuff breaks }{2}

\begin{document}

{\linespread{1}
\begin{specialFRM}First Line \\Second Line \end{specialFRM}
}
\end{document}
```